# Recursively create a directory with a certain owner and group

Tags: go

I would like to recursively create a directory and assign an owner and group for the folders and its parents that were created.

For example, assuming `/var` exists, I want to create `/var/test1/test2/test3`.

I am able to do this using `os.MkdirAll("/var/test1/test2/test3", 0600)`.

However, I also want to set `test1`, `test2`, and `test3`'s `uid` to `user1` and `gid` to `user1`.

It's possible to do so using `os.Chown`, but that requires a lot of manually work. I would need build a tree of the folder and its parents that do not exist before creating the folder chain and then use `os.Chown` on each folder after creation.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that available.  You might be best off copying the `MkdirAll` source and adding an appropriate `Chown` call to do what you want (IIRC there is no way to atomically create a directory with a non-default owner).

Comment: I think that's the best option at the moment, although it feels like a code smell.

Answer (score 7):

A bit like this [`ChownR()` type of function](https://github.com/gutengo/fil/blob/6109b2e0b5cfdefdef3a254cc1a3eaa35bc89284/file.go#L27-L34), the idea would be to filter the walk, and apply the chown only to folders which are part of a path passed in parameter (here `"/var/test1/test2/test3`)

Without filter:

```
func ChownR(path string, uid, gid int) error {
    return filepath.Walk(path, func(name string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err == nil {
            err = os.Chown(name, uid, gid)
        }
        return err
    })
}
```

In other words, with [`filepath.Walk()`](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Walk), there should not be too much "manual work" involved here.

Comment: I think `filepath.Walk()` is a good idea, but I would still need to duplicate the innards of `mkdirall` to work out which folders in the chain do not exist yet, call `mkdirall` to create the folder and then use `filepath.Walk()` to walk through the chain and filter on the list of folders collected in the first them and call `chown`. I think compared to this, making a copy of `mkdirall` and adding a line to call `chown` is much more simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: @F21 no, the walk is only to apply chown, not to create the folders. All you do is check if the current path is a folder, and is a prefix of `/var/test1/test2/test3`: if it is, chown. If it is not, keep walking.

Comment: As another example, let say `/etc/lib/` already exists and I want to create `/etc/lib/test1/test2`. `test1` and `test2` would also need to have their `uid` and `gid` changed, but I would like to leave `/etc/lib` as is. In all of these cases, wouldn't I have to do some processing to see what folders don't exist yet, call `mkdirall` to create them and then use the information from the first step with `filepath.Walk()` to change their `uid` and `gid`? Otherwise, without the information, I would be changing the owner and group of parent folders that already exists.

Comment: @F21 Simply pass 2 parameters: a prefix path (`"/etc/lib/"`) and a path that was just created by mkdirAll (`"test1/test2"`): if the current walked path is a prefix of both (`"/etc/lib/"+"test1/test2"`) but is *not* a prefix of the first parameter (`"/etc/lib/"`), you are good: `chown`. If it is also a prefix of the first parameter, no good: no `chown`.

Comment: Ah, I see. In my case I do not have the luxury of know the prefix before hand, so I would still need to do some processing on each absolute path to determine the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the mkdir process to the user you wish to create directories for. This has the advantage of creating directories with correct permissions and ownership in a single command instead of creating loops or running multiple commands back to back.

Example:

```
import "os/exec"
import "syscall"

func main() {
    // The command here can use flags to create all of the dirs at once
    cmd := exec.Command('mkdir', '-p', '/var/test1/test2/test3/')

    _ = syscall.Umask(0077) // Set umask for this process

    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{}
    cmd.SysProcAttr.Credential = &syscall.Credential{Uid: uid, Gid: gid}

    cmd.Run()

}
```

Since the subprocess "mkdir" runs as the user specified by `uid`, the folders would already have the correct owner. If you get the umask part right, each directory will also have correct permissions.

One caveat: this is not a very portable solution. Using syscall should only be your solution if you are certain your code will only be executing on a specific OS.

Comment: You just saved my bacon. Username checks out. :)

Comment: @farhany glad I could help! For the record, my username started as a joke way back in high school. I don't actually think I'm "vastly superior". lol.

Comment: I am not too aware of SysProcAttrs. Any place you'd recommend for reading about this stuff?

Comment: @farhany Details on the SysProcAttrs are available in the syscall docs here: https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#SysProcAttr. Learning more about how system calls work in general will depend on the operating system and filesystem you're using.